# “Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function”

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

I'm fixing somebody's js code, and got this issue. I'm initializing new video player object(video.js). I have some instance methods. But when in my js code i do something like
`mediaPlayer.instance.playerScrollTo()` it throws me following error. However when i do the same code in chrome console, it executes correctly. I also did `console.log(mediaPlayer.instance)` and in list of methods, i see my method playerScrollTo.
If i've missed some info feel free to ask.

So what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Do you think people are having a chrystal ball in generally?

Comment: not sure which data needs to be provided in this case

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, when called by your code the instance is not yet created (undefined) as to when you call it in the chrome console, everything is already loaded.

Comment: not sure, i'm executing all code for my instance when instance is ready, something like

````ready: function(){my code goes here}````

Comment: If you're really sure that the instance is ready before you call the play() function, maybe you should see if the prototype of that function is properly made. I'm just taking a guess here as I cannot see any of the code.

Answer (score 0):

The `undefined is not a function` error is caused when you try to call a function which is not yet defined. Several things commonly cause it:

### Common causes

1. Order of imports - you have tried to call a function which is defined in a file before you have imported that file in your header.
2. Failure to parse - the file containing the function had an error in it which caused the parser to bail before the function was defined
3. Typo - you called your function myFunction, and tried to call myfunction() for example.

In this instance, playerScrollTo is not defined as an attribute of mediaPlayer.instance.

### Debug

To debug it use FireBug. Set a breakpoint right before the line which throws the error, and inspect the mediaPlayer object.

Best of luck with it.